# Changing color for apalike2 + natbib

Tags: hyperref, color, citing, links

I am ussing apalike2 with natbib and I would like to apply normal, black color instead of light-green in my referrences, for example command:

```
\citep{someone}
```

produces green text:

> (Smith, 2011)

and I would like to have everything exactly the same but in black.
I tried to google and dig into apalike.sty but I cannot find what i am looking for. Does anyone have useful link or know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you load the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package and use its `colorlinks` option. Try the following:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
```

In case you are using a custom class/template that loads `hyperref` by default, add the following to your preamble:

```
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}
```

Comment: Cool! Works like a charm! Will be accepted in two minutes :)